# Can't launch Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm running a VM in Azure with Ubuntu 14.04. I've installed XFCE and use X2GO to remote desktop to the machine.

I've downloaded the VS Code and unzipped the files. When I run Code from a terminal I get the following error:

```
WouterDeKort@UbuntuDev:~/tools/web/visual-studio-code$ ./Code 
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
WouterDeKort@UbuntuDev:~/tools/web/visual-studio-code$ [ , [Error: channel closed] ]
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

*DISCLAIMER ;-) I'm a total Linux newby. I've just installed Linux for the first time today and I have no idea what I'm doing ;-)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [work-a-round is in issue 3451](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3451#issuecomment-217716116). After running this, I was able to launch it from Debian Jessie with LXDE over X2Go.

```
sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem using X2GO and LXDE. Works okay (but slowly) using MobaXterm so apparently this is a problem specific to X2GO.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still wonder what is the best choice if you want to start Visual Studio Code on a headless Ubuntu - the winning combination is:

Ubuntu Server + xfce + nomachine remote desktop

VS Code starts immediately without any hacks, you can set your resolution however you like, and nomachine is blazingly fast.